# How do I change a glyphicon upon clicking it in Bootstrap 3.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have an arrow pointing to the right to allow the user to expand the sidebar, and then change that glyphicon to point to the left. That way, it points to the left so that they understand how to hide the sidebar. I then want it to change back to its default state.

This is what I have currently:

```
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class='hidden-lg'>
        <div class="content-header">
                <h1>
                <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </h1>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: change the glyphicon class on click.

Comment: I'm a noob when it comes to JS and JQuery. You're right, that's exactly what I have to do, but I'm not sure how to code that.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link, koala_dev. I'll definitely check that out. I was thinking of integrating js.OnClick() but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use:

```
$('#menu-toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-arrow-right').toggleClass('glyphicon-arrow-left');
});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5XqyW/1/)

Comment: Apsdehal, thank you very much for your answer. I'm having trouble with this code because the glyphicon goes away after clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#menu-toggle').on('click', function(){
    var iSelector = $(this).find('i:first');
    if(iSelector.hasClass('glyphicon-arrow-right')) {
        iSelector.removeClass('glyphicon-arrow-right')
        iSelector.addClass('glyphicon-arrow-left')
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qz8qt/)

Reference:

- [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)
- [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)
- [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a better way to address this common problem is using CSS's pseudo classes like

```
:after
```

For example

```
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {    
        font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
        content: "\e114";
        float: right;
        color: grey;
        transition: transform 0.5s;
        transform-origin: 8px 7px;
    }
```

And below code for rotating glyphicon

```
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
```

**Please note**: font-family and content may be different if you are using other than bootstrap css library. Also pay attention to the classes decorated or used for your panel.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870611/698127)