# Change glyphicon in button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, onclick

What I want is a basic play-button that onclick plays an audiofile and changes its appearance from glyphicon-play to glyphicon-pause. Further clicking will pause the audio and return to the play-glyphicon.

What I have is a script that lets me play and pause audiofiles, which
I trigger with a button.
What is missing is the switching glyphicon in my button.

```js
function EvalSound(soundobj) {
    var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
    if (thissound.paused) {
      thissound.play();
    } else {
      thissound.pause();
    }
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<audio id="SDJTrack1" preload="none" source src='http://www.salon-du-jazz.de/mp3/La_Version_del_Trabajo_Hoerprobe.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>
</audio>

<audio id="SDJTrack2" preload="none" source src='http://www.salon-du-jazz.de/mp3/No_Matter_Hoerprobe.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>
</audio>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onClick="EvalSound('SDJTrack1')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
</button>1. Song

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onClick="EvalSound('SDJTrack2')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
</button>2. Song
```

I have found several solutions for this e.g.: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24901840/5325923 
Yet I want to add about 20 audio-files on my site and these solutions only seem to work on the first button OR on all buttons at the same time.
What is the best way to handle this?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `html` and `js` like following

```js
function EvalSound(soundobj, button) {
    var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
    if (thissound.paused) {
      thissound.play();
      $(button).find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-pause").addClass("glyphicon-play");
    } else {
      thissound.pause();
      $(button).find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-play").addClass("glyphicon-pause");
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<audio id="SDJTrack1" preload="none" source src='http://www.salon-du-jazz.de/mp3/La_Version_del_Trabajo_Hoerprobe.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>
</audio>

<audio id="SDJTrack2" preload="none" source src='http://www.salon-du-jazz.de/mp3/No_Matter_Hoerprobe.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>
</audio>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onClick="EvalSound('SDJTrack1', this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
</button>1. Song

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onClick="EvalSound('SDJTrack2', this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
</button>2. Song
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I switched the pause and play glyphicons in the function, because else it works the other way around. Works like a charm :)