# Slidetoggle and changing glyphicon

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

This is my first project and my first post here so go easy on me ;)

jQuery is what I'm struggling on. I want to have a button with an arrow pointing down to allow the user to slide out more informations, and when i click it, it should change that glyphicon to point up. So they understand how to hide the informations.

This is what I have currently:

Html:

```
  <section id="about">
    <a name="about"></a>
      <div class="container">
       <h2>Über</h2>
        <p class="topDist">Hier steht erklärender Text über uns.</p>

     <a href="javascript:return false;" id="button" class="btn btn-primary  
     btn-lg">Mehr<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i></a>

    <div id="hidden_content">Hier steht die detallierte Beschreibung. Dieser Text wird erst nach einem Klick auf den Button eingeblendet.</div>
     </div>
  </section>

jQuery

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function(){
            $("#hidden_content").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });

        $('#button').click( function(){
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-up');
        });
```

I found this [How do I change a glyphicon upon clicking it in Bootstrap 3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901731/how-do-i-change-a-glyphicon-upon-clicking-it-in-bootstrap-3-2) and tried to use it for my project. It worked one time but then only the slidetoggle worked and the changing glyphicon didn´t.

I could really use your help here. 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. Change:

```
<span i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i></span>
```

to

```
<span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i></span>
```

Beside this you can combine your `click` listeners and the `toggleClass` into one call.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $("#hidden_content").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-down glyphicon-menu-up');
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section id="about">
  <a name="about"></a>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Über</h2>
    <p class="topDist">foo</p>
    <a href="javascript:return false;" id="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
      more
      <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i></span>
    </a>
    <div id="hidden_content">bar</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much eisbehr! This is great! Only Problem now. I want to have this button on two other places. How can I do that? Only the first button works.

Comment: Thats because `ids` are unique. Use a `class` to identify your buttons. @Jassi

Answer (score 0):

```
use <i class=""> </i> and css #hidden_content {display: none;} for hide your content
```

[Live FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/89mgy3mv/2/)

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#button").click(function() {
        $("#hidden_content").slideToggle("slow");
        });
      });

    $('#button').click(function() {
       $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-   
        down').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-right');
     });

<section id="about">
 <a name="about"></a>
  <div class="container">
   <h2>Über</h2>
 <p class="topDist">Hier steht erklärender Text über uns.</p>

   <a href="javascript:return false;" id="button" class="btn btn-primary     
    btn-lg">Mehr<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down "></i></a>

    <div id="hidden_content">Hier steht die detallierte Beschreibung. Dieser `Text wird erst nach einem Klick auf den Button eingeblendet.</div>`
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with [boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) toggle and jQuery.see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/creativeRosh/xde7cuyz/

```
$('#collapseDiv').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
    });

    $('#collapseDiv').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
    });
```